# Obtaining domain name using Java

Tags: java

How do I obtain the domain name of the machine I am running on using Java?
For eg, my machine is a server whose domain name could be `ec2-44-555-66-777.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

I tried `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` but that doesn't give me the name above. That gives me the hostname which looks similar to `ip-0A11B222`

Comment: Perhaps this might help you a little (have never tried this myself): http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/accessing-the-dusty-corners-dns-java

Comment: I just edited my question. I guess i was really looking for the domain name.

Answer (score 13):

I guess you can try `InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName()` or `InetAddress.getName()` methods. Assuming there is a proper name service running on your net these two should do the trick.

The JavaDocs for [getCanonicalHostName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()) says

> Gets the fully qualified domain name
>   for this IP address. Best effort
>   method, meaning we may not be able to
>   return the FQDN depending on the
>   underlying system configuration.

So if you want to get your local FQDN, you can typically call: `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName()`

Answer (score 7):

**getCanonicalHostName** gives you the fully qualified domain name. I have tried using `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostname()` but it just gets the `hostname` value you see in command line which may or may not contain the fully qualified name.

To check if the fully qualified domain name is set using command line (in linux), use `hostname --fqdn`.

**[getCanonicalHostName](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName())**

> public String getCanonicalHostName() Gets the fully qualified domain
>   name for this IP address. Best effort method, meaning we may not be
>   able to return the FQDN depending on the underlying system
>   configuration.

```
/** Main.java */
import java.net.InetAddress;  

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    byte[] ipAddress = new byte[] {(byte)127, (byte)0, (byte)0, (byte)1 };
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddress);
    String hostnameCanonical = address.getCanonicalHostName();
    System.out.println(hostnameCanonical);
  }
}
```

Example is taken from:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.net/InetAddress/Java_InetAddress_getCanonicalHostName_.htm

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get a domain from a given uri in java , below

```
java.net.URI uri = new URI(url);
String host = uri.getHost();
InternetDomainName internetDomainName = InternetDomainName.from(host);
String domainName = internetDomainName.topPrivateDomain().toString();
```

Answer (score -4):

Do you really need the domain name, or is IP address sufficient? If latter, try using `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem today and found this very easy solution:

```
  System.getenv("userdomain");
```