# How can I get domain name in Java

Tags: java, dns, domain-name, inetaddress

I need domain name.
Currently I am getting domain name as follows

```
InetAddress addr;
String hostnameCanonical;
try{
    addr = InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    hostnameCanonical = addr.getCanonicalHostName();
    String   strDomainName=hostnameCanonical.substring(hostnameCanonical.indexOf(".")+1,      hostnameCanonical.lastIndexOf("."));
    System.out.println("strDomainName = "+strDomainName);
} 
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there any better and efficient way of getting domain name?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891084/obtaining-domain-name-using-java, but that post never got a good answer, IMO.

Comment: @EdStaub why push as duplicate if not a good answer?

Comment: @medokr I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you mean "why do I think this post should be closed?", the answer is "I don't think it should be closed." - I didn't vote to close it, did I?  My comment, in fact, was mostly intended to prevent someone else who quickly sees the other post, without examining the answers, from starting a flood of votes to close.

Answer (score -1):

You can get domain name from your environment.

```
String domainname = System.getenv("USERDOMAIN");
```

Comment: this property contains name of computer

Comment: @Nox Not necessarily, it might also be the name of the network domain (as in the Active Directory domain), but that is still not what is asked for in the question.